# Bootstrap modal issue on different screen sizes

Tags: bootstrap-5

I want to show only the department on a smaller screen size, and the department and location on a bigger screen but this code fails.
why is that?
I tried chat gpt and all the options failed...

```
<div
            class="tab-pane"
            id="departments-tab-pane"
            role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="profile-tab"
            tabindex="0"
          >
            <table id="departmentsTable" class="table table-hover">
              <tr>
                <!--department name-->
                <td class="align-middle text-nowrap"></td>

                <!--department location-->
                <td class="align-middle text-nowrap d-none d-md-table-cell">
                  
                </td>

                <td class="align-middle text-end text-nowrap">
                  <!--edit button-->
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                    data-bs-toggle="modal"
                    data-bs-target="#editDepartmentModal"
                    data-id="1"
                  >
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-pencil fa-fw"></i>
                  </button>

                  <!--delete button-->
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-sm deleteDepartmentTableRowBtn"
                    data-bs-target="#deleteDepartmentModal"
                    data-id="1"
                  >
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-trash fa-fw"></i>
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried d-md-block or d-md-inline instead of d-md-table-cell? What you have should work according to the docs, though. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/